# CakePHP multiple raltions

Tags: cakephp

I want to make a Library in cakePHP and I have some problems with the database relations.
Basically there is a Book object, a Publisher object, a Comment object and a User object.

Every Book can have a Publisher, and multiple Comments. A comment can belongsTo only one book and one user. Now the question is, How can i show the users also in the returned array
I want to show user info for every comment
Here is the code.

```
class Book extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className'     => 'Comment'
        )
    );

    public $belongsTo = 'Publisher';

}

class Publisher extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Book'  =>array(
            'className'     => 'Book'
        )
    );
}

class Comment extends AppModel {

    public $hasOne = array(
        'User'  =>  array(
            'className'     => 'User',
        ),
        'Book'  =>  array(
            'className'     => 'Book',
        )
    );   

}

class User extends AppModel {

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment'   => array(
            'className' => 'Comment'
        )
    );

}
```

And here is the result:

```
[  
   {  
      "Book":{  
         "id":"1",
         "title":"Egy magyar nabob",
         "author_id":"1",
         "publisher_id":"1",
         "punblishing_date":"2014-10-08 00:00:00",
         "creation_date":"2014-10-01 22:48:55"
      },
      "Publisher":{  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Koinonia Kiado",
         "description":"Egy kolozsvari kiado",
         "address":null
      },
      "Comment":[  
         {  
            "id":"3",
            "comment":"Ez egy irto jo konyv :D",
            "user_id":"1",
            "book_id":"1",
            "creation_date":"2014-10-01 23:08:21"
         },
         {  
            "id":"4",
            "comment":"Ujabb COmment :D",
            "user_id":"1",
            "book_id":"1",
            "creation_date":"2014-10-01 23:17:02"
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "Book":{  
         "id":"2",
         "title":"Ket magyar nabob",
         "author_id":"1",
         "publisher_id":"1",
         "punblishing_date":null,
         "creation_date":"2014-10-01 23:17:22"
      },
      "Publisher":{  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Koinonia Kiado",
         "description":"Egy kolozsvari kiado",
         "address":null
      },
      "Comment":[  
         {  
            "id":"5",
            "comment":"Ez ismet egy fantasztikus konyv :D",
            "user_id":"1",
            "book_id":"2",
            "creation_date":"2014-10-01 23:17:49"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe u need the containable behavior ? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: you need to see the recursive options in cakephp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively simple way is to have a getUsers() action in your Users controller, that is similar to the view action, e.g. you can pass it a User ID, but instead of loading a view it will just return an array. Then each time you come across a comment in your Book controller/view you can use requestAction to call Users/getUsers(), passing it Comment.user_id, to return the related User array.